# Openid forbidden error

Tags: php, openid

After I was able to get it (open id library) installed properly, I am facing some problems in getting it to work. I am using the [open id selector](http://jvance.com/pages/JQueryOpenIDPlugin.xhtml) a jquery plugin.

The problem is that when I click on any open id provider image I get an error message saying something like this (after the form is posted to try_auth.php with necessary parameters).

> 'Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /Auth/try_auth.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.'

what is wrong with my configuration.? please help.

**I have hosted my site on a shared hosting.
Does openid implementation has something to do with this.? 

I am asking this because I am not able to set the PHP settings through this method 'ini_set()' in my script.**
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well It took me quite a long time to find a solution for this one.

Actually I had to contact the webhosting service provider support for this because the rules implemented by openid library were interfering with the mod rewrite rules of hosting provider.

They resolved this problem by adding my site to their whitelist.

And then all worked fine (thank God)

hope it helps someone facing this similar problem.

Comment: Great Answer ! Can you explain me how it works. Also does file permission of files, folders also matters when we are in hosting servers.

Comment: We had our website hosted on a shared hosting environment. 
If you are using something other than shared hosting that I think you wouldn't need to do anything extra.
For permission related issue you can refer to documentation.

Comment: This fixed my problem at hostgator. Took a while for them to understand my problem so I linked them to your answer and they fixed it in a few minutes. You Rock!

Answer (score 2):

You say **auth_try.php** in your description.

The server error says **try_auth.php**.

Are you sure the file is there? Can you access http://yourserver/Auth/try_auth.php ? If not, you most probably have a configuration problem in your web server and you'll have to provide more information for others to be able to help.

One question that comes to mind: is this the only PHP file that's not working?

Comment: sorry for misspelling file name, it is now corrected.
well there definitely is some kind of permission setting that needs to be done.. :-( still looking for a solution..

Comment: I'll ask again. Do PHP generally work on your server? If you upload a PHP file containing <?php php_info(); ?> does it work?

Comment: yes PHP does run on the server at which I am hosting my site. Also the whole website is build using PHP, only the openid authentication section is not working. Do I have to use some database sort of mechanism for storing the session info related to the openid.?
I am using filestore module currently.